# Is it useful to add the [.net] tag to a question already tagged [c#]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently came across this [tag-only edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9751567) which added only the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag in addition to the existing [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag. In the past few days I have seen edits like this quite often. However, as C# usually targets .NET (as VB.NET also does), I wonder if adding the .NET tag isn't redundant information and meaningless. I do see that value of adding the .NET tag if the question is really about programming for another framework (like [mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mono)).

So, should I reject edits where I think the addition of the .NET tag is not helpful? And furthermore, should we encourage users to not use the C# and .NET tags together?

Comment: Adding [tag:.net] to a question already tagged with [tag:c#] serves *absolutely no purpose*.

Comment: Don't we have like 20 questions about this already? Not every C# question is about .NET (being the BCL and/or the CLR), and not every .NET question is about C# (being the programming language). Try searching. Of course most people asking questions about C# or .NET don't know these differences.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don´t mean every C#-question is about .NEt, but I think the greatest part of them, thus in thoise cases the information is meaningless.

Comment: @CodeCaster I find it interesting that while 2,752 questions are tagged with the [clr](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/clr/info) tag, only 140 are tagged with the [bcl](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bcl/info) tag. Is the [bcl](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bcl/info) tag superfluous, or is it underutilized?

Comment: @DavidRR to me all it proves is that tags, especially when applied by less knowledgeable users, are less useful than previously thought.

Comment: @CodeCaster Or in the case of [tag:bcl], perhaps under-applied? That is, for those questions that clearly concern the BCL, would it be helpful to tag them as such?

Comment: @DavidRR I find properly applying tags incredibly hard. Is a BCL tag relevant because the question is about some code that uses some types from the BCL? Then you can tag almost every C# question with it, and tag it with .NET while you're at it (as .NET covers BCL/CLR). Or is the BCL tag only valid for questions _about_ BCL types, like _"How to use type X"_ or _"Why does type X not provide method Y"_?

Comment: @CodeCaster Given the extremely limited use of the [tag:bcl] tag, I suspect that some might have the opinion that it should be burninated. (Hmmm, perhaps this should be the basis of another Meta question.)

Comment: This is purely hypothetical since every VB.NET programmer I knew was willing and able to read C# source (it usually doesn't go the other way around, though) and primarily just Googled `ToLowerInvariant` or whatever which brought them to a c# post regardless of tags, but I think ideally it would be nice if all C# posts that asked something primarily about the .NET API (like the question you linked) were tagged [c#] **and** [.net], because somebody could in theory filter only on .NET questions. .NET is unique in that 2 languages use the same API, not the case for something like PyGTK and C GTK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all C# questions is about .NET. You can have a question on C# syntax directly, or class inheritance, or design patterns in C#, or whatever. You can ask very much on C# without talking about .NET API and environment.

But in the question linked, the question is really about .NET.